# What is the difference between `filetype plugin indent on` and `filetype indent on`?

Tags: indentation, filetype

I see one of these two lines in `.vimrc` files. This one seems to be most common:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

But how does it differ from this line:

```
filetype indent on
```

I've found [documentation for the latter](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#:filetype-indent-on), but I'm still confused.

Comment: side tip: you can do `:filetype` to show the filetype settings.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`filetype plugin indent on` is like a combination of these commands:

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

It turns on "detection", "plugin" and "indent" at once. You can check for yourself by reading [`:help :filetype-overview`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#:filetype-overview).

## Detection

What does filetype "detection" do? From the docs:

> Each time a new or existing file is edited, Vim will try to recognize the type
>   of the file and set the 'filetype' option.  This will trigger the FileType
>   event, which can be used to set the syntax highlighting, set options, etc.

This is less confusing if you realise that the `filetype` command is distinct from the `filetype` option. (The command `:filetype...`, the option: `:set filetype...`)

## Plugin

What does the "plugin" part do? From the docs:

> This actually loads the file "ftplugin.vim" in 'runtimepath'.
>
> The result is that when a file is edited its plugin file is loaded (if there
>   is one for the detected filetype).

The file being loaded is not necessarily named `ftplugin.vim`, it could be `ftplugin/html_example.vim` for instance.

## Indent

What does the "indent" part do? From the docs:

> This actually loads the file "indent.vim" in 'runtimepath'.
>
> The result is that when a file is edited its indent file is loaded (if there
>   is one for the detected filetype). indent-expression

Again, the file may not be named `indent.vim`, it could be named `indent/html_example.vim` for instance.

Comment: to make it clear, the name of the file should correspond to the 'filetype' for which is is going to be activated, e.g. either `<type>/foobar.vim` (a subdirectory per filetype) or `<type>_foobar.vim` or simply `<type>.vim` where <type> corresponds to the actual filetype

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Maybe your words can be added to the answer. It's an important point to make the answer complete.